# Keypress event & delete text in textbox & richtextbox

Tags: c#, textbox, richtextbox, keypress

Been trying to solve this problem for hours now, and its frustrating me, hope anyone here can help me!

What im trying to do, is that i want the textbox to clear the text after i have searched for the word i have entered, and the richtextbox to delete whatever is in it when im searching for a new word.

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   

        string downloadedString;
        System.Net.WebClient client;

        string playerName = this.inputText.Text;
        client = new System.Net.WebClient();

        downloadedString = client.DownloadString("http:randomaddress;
        string[] stringSeperator = new string[] { "\n" };
        string[] result;

        result = downloadedString.Split(stringSeperator, StringSplitOptions.None);
        foreach (string s in result)
        {
            Bunch of if statements
        }
    public void SortString(string s)
    {
        //string manipulation
        richTextBox1.Text += manipulate2 + "--" + " ";
    }
    public void SortString2(string s)
    {
        //string manipulation
        richTextBox1.Text += manipulate2 + "--" + " ";
    }
    public void SortString3(string s)
    {
        //string manipulation
        richTextBox1.Text += manipulate2 + "--" + " ";
    }

         private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void True(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Been trying many different approaches but i just cant make it to work.. 
But to say again what it is what i want..
textbox is used for search, the input i get from the search gets showed in the richtextbox.
The search word should be cleared after i have entered the word and searched for it, and the richtextbox needs to clear the former search everytime i search again.

I suppose this is very simple, but havent worked with GUI for more than 2-3 days, used to console :)

Thank you in advance!

Oh and btw, everything else works like it should if that wasnt  clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...just Clear() them both after you have retrieved the search value?

```
string playerName = this.inputText.Text;
this.inputText.Clear();
richTextBox1.Clear();
// ... rest of your code ...
```